# I want to add a row total with a specific name. (e.g- "PremTotal")

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this code IN Snowsql:

```sql
SELECT TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS, SUM(TARGET_NEWQUIKVALF1.MANNLZD)/12 AS PREM
from TARGET_QUIKPLAN Left JOIN TARGET_NEWQUIKVALF1 ON TARGET_QUIKPLAN.PLAN=TARGET_NEWQUIKVALF1.NPLAN
  
group by TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS

Having(((((((((((TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-6041') Or (TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-6042')
             Or (TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-6043') Or (TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-6044')
             Or (TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-6045') Or (TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-6046')
             Or (TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-6047') Or (TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-6048')
             Or (TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-6052') Or (TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-6040')
```

And I want to add row total to give an output that looks like this:

```
FORMS         PREM
L-6040         9
L-6041         2
L-6043         4
.....
.....
(PREMTOTAL)        15
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

`GROUP BY ROLLUP()` will act in a similar way to `GROUP BY`, but will also add a row with the desired totals:

```sql
with data as (select 'a' g, 100 i union all select 'b', 400 union all select 'c', 950)

select g, sum(i)
from data
group by rollup(g);
```

In this case the total sum column will have a null label (instead of the desired "(PREMTOTAL)").

[image]

But! There's a problem with my code there - `HAVING` will apply after `GROUPING` - you will get the total sum before those filters.

```sql
with data as (select 'a' g, 100 i union all select 'b', 400 union all select 'c', 950)

select g, sum(i) the_sum
from data
group by rollup(g)
having the_sum>500
```

The total there is still 1,450. Probably you want this, based in the question:

```sql
with data as (select 'a' g, 100 i union all select 'b', 400 union all select 'c', 950)

select g, sum(the_sum) the_sum
from (
    select g, sum(i) the_sum
    from data
    group by g
    having the_sum>500
)
group by rollup(g);
```

Comment: and if you add a `G is not null` on the inner select you can safe add a wrapper with `COALESCE(g,'PremTotal') as g` and solve all the worlds problems.

Comment: Oh, using `COALESCE` here is a pretty smart solution, thanks!

Comment: and your `WITH data` can be made smaller like so: `with data(g,i) as (select * from values ('a',100),('b', 400), ('c', 950))
`

Comment: Which part "didn't work". Any error message? Output?

Answer (score 0):

So firstly you HAVING filter at the end has a large collection of OR's for the same column which can be rewritten as an IN, which is much more readable.

```
HAVING TARGET_QUIKPLAN.forms IN ('L-6041','L-6042','L-6043','L-6044','L-6045',
     'L-6046','L-6047','L-6048','L-6052','L-6040')
```

The HAVING clause filters after the grouping, so is really good for rules like sum all of X and only keep the sum's over 300, where your HAVING is filtering on the grouping column, thus should be a WHERE clause to reduce data read, if possible.

```
SELECT 
    tqp.forms
    ,SUM(tnq.mannlzd)/12 AS prem
FROM target_quikplan AS tqp
LEFT JOIN target_newquikvalf1 AS tnq
    ON tqp.plan=tnq.nplan
WHERE tqp.forms IN ('L-6041','L-6042','L-6043','L-6044','L-6045',
    'L-6046','L-6047','L-6048','L-6052','L-6040')
GROUP BY tqp.forms
```

to answer your question with the answer Felipe provided, it becomes:

```
SELECT 
    tqp.forms
    ,SUM(tnq.mannlzd)/12 AS prem
FROM target_quikplan AS tqp
LEFT JOIN target_newquikvalf1 AS tnq
    ON tqp.plan=tnq.nplan
WHERE tqp.forms IN ('L-6041','L-6042','L-6043','L-6044','L-6045',
    'L-6046','L-6047','L-6048','L-6052','L-6040')
GROUP BY ROLLUP(tqp.forms)
```

and with my comment you can rename the "total" which is NULL after the rollup via COALESCE

```
SELECT COALESCE(forms, '(PREMTOTAL)') AS forms
    ,PREM
FROM (
    SELECT 
        tqp.forms
        ,SUM(tnq.mannlzd)/12 AS prem
    FROM target_quikplan AS tqp
    LEFT JOIN target_newquikvalf1 AS tnq
        ON tqp.plan=tnq.nplan
    WHERE tqp.forms IN ('L-6041','L-6042','L-6043','L-6044','L-6045',
        'L-6046','L-6047','L-6048','L-6052','L-6040')
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(tqp.forms)
)
```